# EitherT not properly upcasting to common trait super type (Scala 3)

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers

When chaining a for comprehension with `EitherT`, the compiler is having issues upcasting my errors to their common ancestor type.

I have the following type definitions in my code:

```
sealed trait Error
object Error:
  case object Error1 extends Error
  case class Error2(someParams) extends Error
```

So far so good. I then had this trait where I expose this stuff:

```
trait SomeInterface[F[_]]:
  def someMethod(params): F[Either[Error1.type, Type1]]
  def otherMethod(params): F[Either[Error2, Type2]]
```

Then inside my logic I'm chaining them in this way:

```
for {
  t1 <- EitherT(someMethod)
  t2 <- EitherT(otherMethod)
yield t2
```

This should work in theory, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Found: EitherT[F, Error2, Type2]
Expected: EitherT[F, Error1.type, Any]
```

I already tried changing my interfaces so that they return the common type, but then it has trouble casting it when I implement.

I also tried passing type parameters in the `EitherT` constructor, but same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a great FP expert to be honest so I'm not sure whether my solution is the "clean" one, but whenever I had this kind of problem I fixed by importing `cats.syntax.bifunctor.*` and calling `leftWiden[Error]` on the `EitherT`.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @[stefanobaghino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3314107/stefanobaghino) said, using `leftWiden[Error]` fix the problem.

The **root cause** of the error is because `Left` type in `Either` and `EitherT` in cats effect is **invariant** and you will get **type mismatch**.

The article [Monad transformers and cats - 3 tips for beginners](https://blog.softwaremill.com/monad-transformers-and-cats-3-tips-for-beginners-196fabe58daa) might help to understand why and also show other tips about error handling.

> Let’s say you want to model your business errors as a hierarchy of types extending common type `CatError`:
>
> ```scala
> sealed abstract class CatError(msg: String)
>
> case object CatIsHungry extends CatError("Cat is hungry!")
> case object CatIsSleepy extends CatError("Cat is sleepy!")
> case object CatIsIgnoringYou extends CatError("Cat is ignoring you!")
> case object CatIsNotInTheMood extends CatError("Cat is not int the mood!")
> ```
>
> Then let’s create two methods both returning nested `IO` and `Either`. The error type of first `Either` will be `CatIsIgnoringYou` and `CatIsNotInTheMood` for the second one. Since both error types extend `CatError`, you > could assume that if you fix the error type of resulting `EitherT` to `CatError` there would be no compilation errors.
>
> ```scala
> import cats.data.EitherT
> import cats.effect.IO
>
> case class Cat(readyToPlay: Boolean, hasOtherPlans: Boolean, isSleepy: Boolean)
>
> def callTheCat(cat: Cat): IO[Either[CatIsIgnoringYou.type, Cat]]
>   = IO(Either.cond(!cat.hasOtherPlans, cat.copy(readyToPlay = true), CatIsIgnoringYou))
>
> def playWithCat(cat: Cat): IO[Either[CatIsNotInTheMood.type, Unit]] =
>     IO(Either.cond(!cat.isSleepy, (), CatIsNotInTheMood))
>
> //shold compile, right?
> def haveFun(cat: Cat): EitherT[IO, CatError, Unit] = for {
>     readyCat <- EitherT(callTheCat(cat))
>     _ <- EitherT(playWithCat(readyCat))
> } yield ()
> ```
>
> Unluckily, it’s not the case. `Left` type in `Either` and `EitherT` in cats effect is **invariant** and you will get **type mismatch**:
>
> [image: compilation error]
>
> Again fixing the problem is straightforward. You need to use function `leftWiden` which lets you broaden the left type of `EitherT` to more general `CatError`. It’s usually enough to use `leftWiden` on the last function call > in `flatMap` chain or for-comprehension:
>
> ```scala
> import cats.data.EitherT
> import cats.effect.IO
> import cats.syntax.all._ // new import
>
> // ... same code
>
> def haveFun(cat: Cat): EitherT[IO, CatError, Unit] = for {
>     readyCat <- EitherT(callTheCat(cat))
>     _ <- EitherT(playWithCat(readyCat)).leftWiden[CatError] // used leftWiden to fix the issue
> } yield ()
> ```